# Command Line Tool in Python to update/append json configuration file

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, command-line-interface

### Requirements

I am creating a `Python3` module which I wish port to an embedded board (using Yocto) and using `setuptools` and not on PyPi.

I have a `conf.json` file which is in the main module folder:

```
 myApp
| -- submodule-1
| -- submodule-2
| -- main.py
| -- conf.json
```

The reason for such selection of the `conf.json` file is due to the [Python Packaging tutorial](https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/non-code-files.html) which mentions about **non-code-files**

This becomes a bit complicated as I understand that once the package is installed (using `pip install .`) the destination folder becomes more complicated to reach:

```
/usr/local/bin/python3/dist-packages/myApp/myApp/conf.json
```

(something similar to above)

#### Usage

1. There is particular case where initially the user for the app triggers some binaries to obtain some relevant information about a process and needs to add them to the `conf.json` later.

Data:

```
configVals: {

   123453: {
      'type': 'engine-params',
      'baudrate': 115200,
      'baud': 500
   },
   245633: {
       // similar to above
   }
}
```

This above should be appended to the `conf.json` with some respective key within the structure.

2. Update information in `conf.json` to **Enable/Disable** some functionality

data:

```
 previously
 {
    "gps": {
        "active": true
     }
 }

 now 
 {
    "gps": {
       "active": false

     }
 }
```

### Plan

I was looking into making a command line tool for the user:

```
change-config  --system gps --key active --value false
```

or

```
 change-config --configVals --list {1234}
```

with perhaps `kwargs` and `argParse` but found out that `kwargs` doesn't work like Python Functions.

Is there a some Open-Source Implementation that does something similar to what my requirements are?

#### Last Resort

I can add `conf.json` in `/etc/myApp/` and user can update it there.

Comment: It sounds like all you need is `argparse` and `json`, both in the standard library.

Comment: @GeorgeG I know they are standard but parsing json using `argparse` via the command line is not that easy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel this question is not so much about python but about software deployment/release. I have also the strong feeling you're asking for software recommendations here rather than code, so I hope this get's moved to [Software Recs](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/). Either way here is my advice:

1. Do not include configuration files in your python package. If you're targeting *nix systems with your tool, read your config files from `/etc/`, the users home directory or some file set in an environment variable. All of these are *de facto* ways to access configuration files and users will expect your software to adhere to one of them (On a personal note, it pains me when I have to use a program that doesn't comply with this convention)
2. To manipulate JSON files via command line there's [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/). If you want to make your users life easier you can write your own program that reads from the command line and saves into your JSON file. I'm not aware of a python tool to do exactly that but it should not be too hard to write one. If you're going to do that.

   2.1 Use [click](http://click.pocoo.org/5/) to parse your command line.
   2.2 Use [docopt](http://docopt.org/), it is simple
3. Finally I would tell you to stick to my advice in (1) **and** also let your users edit the configuration file with their favorite editor. *nix users are quite happy with editing configuration files manually, or using `sed`, or `perl`, or whatever method that doesn't imply having a "configuration tool".

Comment: I think you are right. If it is *NIX system then `/etc/` is the way to go and easier. Thanks.